# ¿Como ejecutar código php solo una vez?

Tags: php

Tengo este código el cual se ejecuta el 1 de cada mes y me trae los usuarios mejor evaluados y después los inserta en otra tabla y les da una fecha fin a 30 días, pero el problema que estoy viendo es que me ejecuta la función todo el día y solo quiero que se ejecute una vez el 1 de cada mes, ya intente con una condición de `$_SESSION` pero al borrar el historial del navegador y cargar la pagina vuelve a ejecutar la función.

Este es el código:

```
// TZ de México
    putenv('TZ=America/Mexico_City');

    $fecha = date("j");

    //var_dump($fecha);

    if($fecha == 1){

        if(!isset($_SESSION['first_run'])){

            $_SESSION['first_run'] = 1;

                $contMeGusta = Controlador::ctrContadorMeGusta();

                $date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $date_future = strtotime('+30 day', strtotime($date_now));
                $date_future = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_future);

                foreach ($contMeGusta as $key => $value2){

                    $nomUsuario = $value2["nom_usuario"];

                    $insert = Controlador::ctrInsertar($nomUsuario, $date_future);

                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Podrías crear en la BD una tabla con un campo que sirva para saber si ya se ejecutó o no, hacer una condicional: si el campo es `false` quiere decir que no se ha ejecutado entonces ejecutar la función y al finalizar cambiar ese campo por true, y así la función ya no se ejecutará más veces. Al siguiente día devolver el valor a false

Comment: Este tipo de cosas es recomendable hacerlo mediante cron job

Comment: Gracias por responder @EmilianoPamont no tengo mucha experiencia en BD, pero eso mismo que me dices se podría hacer en PHP? o si me pudieras explicar bien como lo podría hacerlo en la BD

Comment: @sagitorr se puede hacer uso de Bases de Datos con PHP la más común para PHP es mySQL te dejo este link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp cuando tengas nociones más fuertes de ello puedes volver a leer mi anterior comentario y guiarte sobre lo que puedes hacer

Comment: Aparte de lo recomendado podrías crear una `cookie` con un día de vida y así no tendrás el problema de tu sesión. Al insertar los datos lo pones en valor `true` y antes de insertar compruebas el valor de dicha cookie si es `true` o `false`.

Comment: Tu PHP solo se ejecuta cuando lo ejecutas. No vas a llegar a una solución que sea aceptable. Esto como ha dicho antes @Xerif es más correcto con un cron. Podrías complicar más la condición (el día 1 del mes, a las 12:01, por ej) pero solo se ejecutará ese día a esa hora si tú ejecutas el PHP. Hay soluciones más avanzadas (con reactphp puedes usar eventos cron) pero es muy complejo para tener a mano soluciones con cron

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un evento en la base de datos y en el podrías indicar la frecuencia con la que quieres que se ejecute.

Algo como esto

```html
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
EVENT
[IF NOT EXISTS]
event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
[COMMENT 'comment']
DO sql_statement;
 
schedule:
AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
| EVERY interval
[STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
[ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
 
interval:
quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

Los eventos permiten automatizar tareas y realizar acciones que se repiten de acuerdo al tiempo que establezcas.

Comment: esto no es una respuesta sino un comentario de que hacer, pero no indica el como; revisa [answer]